# Как реализовать запрос по поиску

Tags: java, postgresql

такой вот вопросик, есть контекстный поиск который делается с помощью `like`
например: `... and kiz like '" + kiz +"%'"` получается контекстный поиск, если я ввожу в `input` например `дх`, мне выдает и `дх` и `дх1` и `дх 2`, нужно сделать так что бы выдавало только то что я введу, если `like` заменить на `=` и убрать `%`, ищет правильно, но если `input` пустой при первом запуске приложения, данные не находит, потому что в базе нет пустого поля `kiz`, как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1:

```
 AND (kiz = 'input' OR 'input' = '')
```

Вариант 2:

```
AND (kiz = 'input' OR length('input') = 0)
```